# Define IFC Mvd on posting translation job

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

On translation of RVT file to SVF, I also want to post a job to translate and download an IFC file. Opening that IFC file after translation, it seems to use CV1 - Coordination View 1, which is a very old Model View Definition (hardly in use anymore and only for IFC2x3). If I export same RVT file in Revit 2016 with newest IFC exporter downloaded, choosing CV1 as an option, the file size of the IFC file translated from Revit is half the size of that from Forge. Is there a way to specify which MVD to use for the IFC translation using Model Derivative API, as it is in Revit (CV2, COBIE, IFC4 RV/DTV)? Since it seems that Forge uses the Revit IFC exporter, I would anticipate this be an option, but so far I have not succeeded finding it.

Comment: As I know, that might not be possible currently. I'm checking with our engineering team and will get you back A.S.A.P.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very important

Answer (score 0):

**2019 Update**

Just got informed, the issue `REVIT-125299` has been resolved according to our engineering team. So, please try to submit the job body like below, use `IFCExportOption` instead, then you will obtain an IFC exported with the specified export setting. Cheer!

```
{
    "input": {
      "urn": "{{base64URN}}"
    },
    "output": {
      "formats": [
        {
          "type": "IFC",
          "views": [
            "2d",
            "3d"
          ],
          "advanced": {   //!<<< export options start 
             "IFCExportOption": "IFC4 Design Transfer View" 
          }               //!<<< export options end 
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```

**The old**

After checking with our engineering team, Forge MD has supported to set IFC export options up like in Revit. For example,

```
{
    "input": {
      "urn": "{{base64URN}}",
      "compressedUrn": false,
      "rootFilename": "{{Filename}}"
    },
    "output": {
      "formats": [
        {
          "type": "IFC",
          "views": [
            "2d",
            "3d"
          ],
          "advanced": {   //!<<< export options start 
             "exportSettingName": "IFC4 Design Transfer View"   
          }               //!<<< export options end 
        }
      ]
    }
 }
```

IFC exporter will try to seek for the saved export settings in your uploaded RVT based on the `exportSettingName`. If there is no matched setting, it will use `IFC2X3` by default **as I experience**.

But there is a issue related to this feature, the output might not matched with the export settings, it has been logged as request id `REVIT-125299` in our internal case system to make our team to allocate time to investigate. Apologies for any inconvenience caused.

However, you can sent the request id to `forge.help@autodesk.com` in the future to track updates. Thank you~

**P.S. The above code sample might be changed in the future, please follow with the official documents: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/**